# how to design card or container view in flutter?

Tags: flutter

i want to design card or container like below image, how i can design this type lay out of card or container any one idea :
[image]

I'm trying to design a upcoming ride view , and am wondering how to add the black color at the left and end of this card widget where

Comment: `Stack` and `Positioned` widget is the simples way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey by using `Container` and `Column` and `Row` u can create this view.. no `need for stack` i guess  below is the sample code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: Text(
            "Upcoming Rides",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                          5,
                        ),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            offset: Offset(1, 1),
                            spreadRadius: .5,
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(
                              .4,
                            ),
                            blurRadius: 5.0,
                          ),
                        ],
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(5),
                                ),
                              ),
                              height: 150,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          "Raid Details",
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                        ),
                                        Icon(
                                          Icons.edit_calendar_outlined,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          "11:30 am | 12 June 2023",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color:
                                                  Colors.black.withOpacity(.5)),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          "Raid Details",
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 50,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Cancel",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the output sample
[image: output]

Comment: Thank you so much for your and helpful response! @mageshmagi

Answer (score 0):

```
         Material(
                  elevation: 3.0,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 250,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 215,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
```

[image: demo]